# MUI DataGrid ColumnDef: the row is not available on the valueOptions prop of the column definition

Tags: material-ui, datagrid, columndefinition

I am using a DataGridPro component with different columns.
One one the columns is defined like this:

[image]

This issue is that I am trying to understand why the row is not available in the valueOptions prop of the column definition.
I would like to be able to populate the choices based on a list that is available on the row in another field.
But I get this error when I try to read the row:

[image]

Can you please help?  The grid is populated with lots of rows coming from an api fetch.
Every other column is working fine accept this one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that it was my bad. My column object was used twice with different parameters and so, yes, the row was not available for the second case.